# Why won't this add things to the database?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a follow system - a bit like what Twitter has. For some reason, nothing is added to the database when I click the 'follow' button. How can I fix this?

The code I have is:

```
$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$u_id1 = $_GET['id'];
$check = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM follow WHERE user_one='$my_id' AND user_two='$u_id1'");    
if(mysqli_num_rows($check) == 1) {
        echo "<a href='follow_action.php?do=unfollow&user_id=$u_id1'>Unfollow</a> ";
        }   
        else {
        echo "<strong><a href='follow_action.php?do=follow&user_id=$u_id1'>Follow</a></strong>";
        }
```

In the follow_action.php document, I have this code:

```
$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
$followAction = "INSERT INTO follow VALUES ('', '$my_id', '$user_id')";
$unfollowAction = "DELETE FROM 'follow' WHERE 'user_one'='$my_id' AND 'user_two'='$user_id'";
$u_id1 = $_GET['user_id'];
if( $do == ['follow'] ) {
    mysqli_query( $con, $followAction );
}
if( $do == ['unfollow'] ) {
    mysqli_query( $con, $unfollowAction );
}
$user_id3 = $_GET['user_id'];
header('Location:users.php?id='.$user_id3);
```

The follow table in the database has these rows: id, user_one and user_two - with user_one being the logged in user and user_two the user who is wanted to be followed.

Comment: in follow_action where do you set `$do`?You probably meant `$u_id1` in the if conditions.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0):

You Change in follow_action.php file
like this

```
$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
$do = $_GET['do'];
$followAction = "INSERT INTO follow VALUES ('', '$my_id', '$user_id')";
$unfollowAction = "DELETE FROM 'follow' WHERE 'user_one'='$my_id' AND 'user_two'='$user_id'";
$u_id1 = $_GET['user_id'];
if( $do == 'follow' ) {
mysqli_query( $con, $followAction );
}
if( $do == 'unfollow' ) {
mysqli_query( $con, $unfollowAction );
}
$user_id3 = $_GET['user_id'];
header('Location:users.php?id='.$user_id3);
```

You not get **do** value .do value is follow or unfollow

you Try die(mysql_error()) near it show error in your sql query

```
mysqli_query( $con, $followAction ) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. Do you know what else might be wrong?

Comment: There is no error. When the link is clicked, nothing happens.

Comment: you url like this localhost/projectname/follow_action.php?do=unfollow&user_id=2' format  ?

Comment: Yes, should I change it to something else?

Comment: you use die() function like this mysqli_query( $con, $followAction ) or die(mysqli_error());

Comment: It doesn't give me any error. Is there anything else I could do?